# How to train a set of images including the Nan in deep learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to train a deep learning model using GAN. The data set that I am using is the grid data which they have Nan values. Therefore, the loss function calculated Nan. So far, I thought that I can use the mask. However, the masked-array can not be saved or load. I have tried the following code, but the A (masked-array) can not be saved in dataset_pressureNotNan. would you mind helping e with this issue?
Thanks

```
`

    dataset=np.load('Dataset.npy')
    
dataset_pressureNotNan=np.zeros(shape=(dataset_pressure.shape[0],
dataset_pressure.shape[1], dataset_pressure.shape[2]))

    
    for i in range(dataset_pressure.shape[0]):
        A=np.ma.array(dataset_pressure[i,:,:], mask=np.isnan(dataset_pressure[i,:,:]))
        dataset_pressureNotNan[i,:,:]=A`
```

Comment: What if you replace the NaN with a very small number: np.finfo(float).eps?

Comment: I have not tried that. Let me check it and get back to you. Thanks a million